# Session key changing for same client(HttpClient)

Tags: servlets, smalltalk, visualworks

I am trying to figure out what i might be missing here.

I have a Servlet TestServlet which is ,

```
Smalltalk defineClass: #TestServlet
    superclass: #{VisualWave.HttpServlet}
    indexedType: #none
    private: false
    instanceVariableNames: ''
    classInstanceVariableNames: ''
    imports: ''
    category: ''
```

with method for get:

```
doGet: aRequest response: aResponse

    aResponse write: aRequest session key
```

Now with this i run a workspace code

```
client := HttpClient new.
    Transcript
        show: (client executeRequest: (HttpRequest
                            get: 'http://localhost:8008/servlet/TestServlet'))
                    value value;
        cr.
    Transcript
        show: (client executeRequest: (HttpRequest
                            get: 'http://localhost:8008/servlet/TestServlet'))
                    value value;
        cr.
    Transcript
        show: (client executeRequest: (HttpRequest
                            get: 'http://localhost:8008/servlet/TestServlet'))
                    value value;
        cr.
    Transcript
        show: (client executeRequest: (HttpRequest
                            get: 'http://localhost:8008/servlet/TestServlet'))
                    value value;
        cr
```

Here every 3rd request gets be a different session key.

When i debugged i found that  in the method Response => setSessionKey
`webRequest`  wont have a cookie named `cookieName` , so it will set the cookie.
Later in the second request `webRequest` have a cookie name and so it wont set the cookie.So the next (third) request will initiate a new session and since it wont have `cookieName` in `webRequest` , it will set the cookieName with the new session key which will remain in the fourth session too.

Is this expected behavior and so am i missing something? Or can it be done in a different way so that this behavior wont happen?

```
setSessionKey

    self session
        ifNotNil: 
            [| cookieName |
            cookieName := webRequest webSite sessionCookieName.
            (webRequest cookieValueAt: cookieName)
                ifNil: [self cookieAt: cookieName put: self session key]]
```

Looking forward for smalltalk gurus to help me here.

Thanks in Advance.

PS: I know we can set the session cookie to the response , but i am looking for a different solution or may be a more correct one. Also i would like to get the reason why this happens.Thanks.